# Does installing more desktop environments break my system?

Tags: gnome, kde, xubuntu

I plan to install Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit and then install Xfce, Gnome and KDE desktops from USC.

Will it break my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it should not break the Ubuntu. And if you want to remove some of the xfce,gnome,kde desktops this might interest you: [How to completely remove desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73993/how-to-completely-remove-desktop).