# Can changing desktops environments affect my programs/personal data?

Tags: desktop-environments

If I install a different desktop environment on ubuntu, will it delete files or programs installed earlier?

Could I use those programs installed with ubuntu if I replace the environment with xfce?

Comment: Installing a DE will not affect installed programs. Take a look at my answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162516/switching-window-manager-desktop-environments/162518#162518), it might help you with the installation.

Comment: Agree. `xfce4` just installs XFCE, while `xubuntu-desktop` installs xfce4 **and** might install new programs (those who do not belong to `ubuntu-desktop`).

Answer (score 2):

Changing Desktop Environments is like changing clothes, yourself will be the same. There's almost 0 risk of data loss (you always should do backups) and almost no glitches (Unity and Gnome 3 don't play well together). There's no risk of something bad happening whatsoever.

Comment: Does changing DE change drivers installed? Any connection of drivers and DE?  My Laptop is new but RAM is just 4GB. Nvidia and Realteck are there. Also, sleep-wakeup problem comes easily. Ubuntu 16 works fine but slow.

Comment: @SatyaPrakash no. DE is way too low in the stack to even affect kernel modules. Report a bug instead.