# Logging out from Ubuntu takes too long

Tags: unity, lightdm, xfce, upstart, logout

When I first had only Unity as a desktop manager, I didn't need to log out so I'm not sure if this issue has been around before. I'm say so because It's important to know that I currently have Xfce 4.12 installed.

I'm still experimenting so I'm logging out\in a lot. When I logout, I see the following message:

```
* Starting LightDM Display Manager
* Stopping Send an Event to indicate plymouth is  up
* Starting startpar bridge for notification of upstart job start/stop
* Stopping startpar bridge for notification of upstart job start/stop
* Starting Mount network filesystems
* Stopping Mount network filesystems
* Starting startpar bridge for notification of upstart job start/stop
* Stopping startpar bridge for notification of upstart job start/stop
```

Would someone please:
1. Explain what does these messages mean ? 
2. Why is logging out taking too much time ?
3. When I start Ubuntu, it take too much longer than what it would take to start Ubuntu on Virtualbox ! could this be related to these messages ?

Comment: By logging out, do you mean `Log Out` or `Shutdown`? And how do you activate it: from the `Action Buttons' panel plug-in or from the `App Menu`?

Comment: I mean `Log out`, when I'm using Xfce, I sometimes like to switch to Unity, so I logout from Xfce by clicking on my name (i.e. on the top panel) and chose to logout.

Comment: Right, then this is the `Action Buttons` panel plug-in. Have you tried `Applications Menu > Log Out`? Do you see the same issue.

Comment: I removed Xfce after I asked this question. But for the sake of answering your comments, I installed `xfce4` but only `xfce4` this time. I logged in and did as you suggested `Applications Menu > Log Out`, the logout was WAY faster. I logged in again and tried the `Action Buttons`, but it was fast too !! I'm not sure what changed since I uninstalled xfce !

But I still need to understand what's going on here ? how can I investigate this issue if it happens again ? Why did you suggest using the `Applications Menu > Log Out` ? What aspect of linux should I read about to understand all of this ?

Comment: By I only installed `xfce4`, I mean I didn't install `xubuntu-desktop` along with it. Last time I installed both, probably `xubuntu-desktop` alongside `unity` causes some issues.

Comment: Having xfce alongside unity [should NOT cause issues](http://askubuntu.com/questions/149515/will-removing-xubuntu-packages-affect-unity/406798#406798). I would be more suspicious of the `Starting Mount network filesystems`; I have been reading elsewhere that such operations can potentially slow down the system. And maybe this is what you were experiencing at some point.