# How do I restore Boot GUI and Login of Ubuntu 13.10 to the original?

Tags: lightdm, login-screen

Okay, so I installed a few extra desktop environments, one of which was the Xubuntu pack, and it replaced my login screen and Boot GUI as mentioned. I made the mistake of trying to purge Lightdm and reinstalling it, but the boot GUI hasn’t changed and the login screen is even further from what I wanted. What can I do to correct it? All I want is what came with Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy.

Answer (score 1):

Set Lightdm as default Desktop Manager:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Uninstall Xubuntu:

[How to remove xubuntu-desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92084/how-to-remove-xubuntu-desktop)

Comment: Well, that worked marvellously, though the login screen isn't exactly what I was hoping for, it certainly is a lot closer.

Answer (score 1):

### For boot logo

Run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

This will show all your themes. Just choose appropriate number.
For example:

```
Есть 3 варианта для альтернативы default.plymouth (предоставляет /lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth).

Выбор   Путь                                                               Приор Состояние
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /lib/plymouth/themes/lubuntu-logo/lubuntu-logo.plymouth                 150       автоматический режим
  1            /lib/plymouth/themes/lubuntu-logo/lubuntu-logo.plymouth                 150       ручной режим
* 2            /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-faded-screen/ubuntu-faded-screen.plymouth   20        ручной режим
  3            /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth                   100       ручной режим

Нажмите enter, чтобы сохранить текущий выбор[*], или введите выбранное число:
```

### For login screen

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```