# Frozen splash screen after removing packages

Tags: boot, xubuntu, 20.10, xrdp, motherboard

I am fairly new to the scene. After downloading Ubuntu I was trying to set up a remote desktop server with `xrdp` and in the process I thought it would be a good opportunity to download another desktop environment as the main environment for my remote desktop. However, installing xubuntu-desktop came with many packages that I wasn't expecting which cluttered up my applications. I followed this: [How to remove xubuntu-desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92084/how-to-remove-xubuntu-desktop) guide to remove them (I ran the commands from both the first and second responses), but applications were still appearing in the software store, so I also did some removing there. Afterwards I restarted my computer, but now I get stuck after GRUB -> boot menu -> motherboard (ASUS) logo screen.

I have tried:

1. setting splash screen to "nosplash" (it still freezes on a black screen) in the boot config
2. adding "nomodeset" to config file
3. booting into recovery mode and repairing dpkg files

Anyone know what is going on?

edit-1
I tried switching my display port off of my NVIDIA card to the motherboard, and that gets me past the splash screen, but then I get stuck on a full-screen terminal.

edit-2
I reinstalled xubuntu in recovery mode and now I can access everything as usual (even the normal Gnome desktop). I still have a bunch of xubuntu junk on my system though that I am nervous about touching. If anyone knows what happened or how to remove it safely that would be great!

Comment: If this is a "new installation" and you don't mind starting over, install Xubuntu. That will be the simplest way to accomplish the goal.

Comment: I'll try that. I am worried that in the process of trying to purge xubuntu I swept something else up with it.

Comment: I reinstalled xubuntu in recovery mode and that fixed...everything (other than the fact that I still have a bunch of xubuntu junk everywhere again). Thank you!