# I am stuck in XFCE with no option to change to GNOME

Tags: xfce, desktop-environments, recovery-mode

I am  usually using Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome DE. Since my laptop is slow, I wanted so see how it will work with XFCE. In the login screen, I switched to XFCE and it was a terrible experience with very slow responses.  Now, I can not get back to Gnome, I get no option to chose DE, it is booting into XFCE directly and the screen is stuck. How do I change it back to Gnome using recovery mode? I am using HP laptop.

Comment: At the DM (*display manager that performs greeter functions*) you select which desktop you'll login in with when you select/enter your username & password. When you installed `xubuntu-desktop` (*you weren't specific as to how you installed it so I've made assumption*) you were asked which DM you want to be used (Xubuntu/Xfce defaults to a different DM to GNOME thus the question), and it's how you answered this question that dictates how you're asked to select desktop. If you have *autologin* enabled, you need to logout to get asked.

Comment: I did not install any thing, just choose XFCE from the DM menu. Now it goes directly into XFCE. I do not have the choice, It does not give this option to select DE. Therefore, I asked about recovery mode. Nothing works in GUI.

Comment: You said you "*switched to XFCE*" which I don't know what what you meant.. This install I'm using is a Ubuntu install initially; on which I added `xubuntu-desktop` (ie. XFCE), `lubuntu-desktop` (was LXDE but now is LXQt), `ubuntu-mate-desktop`..... ie. I added them so I could switch from one desktop to another just by logout & logging back in switching desktops (at the DM; which is `sddm` for me; having `gdm3` for Ubuntu/GNOME, and `lightdm` for ...).. What do you mean by "*switched to XFCE*"   (if you re-installed; your GNOME is likely gone)

Comment: "switched to XFCE" means choosing XFCE in the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

I removed  xubutnu and xfce installation using the root terminal in the recovery mode.  :[See link here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92084/how-to-remove-xubuntu-desktop)

Comment: You've answered your own question; though I don't see how this does.. either way removing the `xubuntu-desktop` will still leave parts behind (eg. the `plymouth` logo, which will say Xubuntu until you change that back to whichever you want to use).

Comment: After I purged xubuntu and XFCE, I got the login screen back and the XFCE option was not available anymore. That all I needed.