# How can I remove gnome from a kubuntu 12.04 install?

Tags: gnome, kubuntu

I have a kubuntu 12.04 system to which I added gnome (unity) but I'm now wanting to remove gnome as I don't think I'll ever use it. doing apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop doesn't remove the packages, so how can I safely remove all the gnome components?  I don't really want to do a clean install if I can avoid it.

Comment: Desktops are meta packages: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages. These packages do not contain actual software, they simply depend on other packages to be installed. Earlier in the AskUbuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/73993/how-to-completely-remove-desktop

Answer (score 3):

I suggest , if you want to remove gnome, unity and ubuntu-desktop, try the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntu-desktop

sudo apt-get remove --purge unity

sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome
```

I would also suggest you to run this last command just to be on the safe side, if any  kde applications get removed, it will be installed back.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop kubuntu-restricted-extras
```