# How do I remove lubuntu-desktop?

Tags: desktop-environments, lubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to completely remove desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73993/how-to-completely-remove-desktop)

I wanted to try lubuntu-desktop so I installed it with `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`.

But when I didn't like it I wanted to remove it with `sudo apt-get remove lubuntu-desktop`(then with auto-remove) but my startup / shutdown screen does still say lubuntu.

So how do I remove lubuntu-desktop?

- Atempt one:

`sudo apt-get remove lubuntu-desktop`

I've also tried to remove and install ubuntu-desktop, but none has worked.

Comment: The problem you're trying to fix and the question you ask are actually unrelated.  The startup/shutdown splash is determined by plymouth.  Removing Lubuntu won't affect that.  If you want to change the splash, you can do [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/122084/43660) or remove the plymouth theme (as you did in your own answer).

BUT, as I mention below (and indicated by the answers), removing `lubuntu-desktop` does not remove Lubuntu.  To do that, you should follow one of the other answers.

Comment: but when I installed Lubuntu the splash said lubuntu, and now when I've removed it it say's Xubuntu...

Comment: @Chan-Ho Suh What answer here works then? because I can't find any...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/puregnome

Note, this applies only to Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric)

If you are using kubuntu or xubuntu, check for purekubuntu/xubuntu entries.

```
sudo apt-get remove abiword abiword-common abiword-plugin-grammar abiword-plugin-mathview ace-of-penguins audacious audacious-plugins chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n chromium-codecs-ffmpeg elementary-icon-theme esound-common galculator gdebi gdebi-core giblib1 gnome-icon-theme-full gnome-mplayer gnome-system-tools gnome-time-admin gnumeric gnumeric-common gnumeric-doc gpicview gtk2-engines-pixbuf guvcview hardinfo indicator-status-provider-pidgin leafpad libabiword-2.8 libaiksaurus-1.2-0c2a libaiksaurus-1.2-data libaiksaurusgtk-1.2-0c2a libaudclient2 libaudcore1 libaudiofile0 libavcodec53 libavformat53 libavutil51 libbinio1ldbl libcddb2 libcompfaceg1 libcue1 libdca0 libdirectfb-1.2-9 libdiscid0 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libenca0 libencode-locale-perl libept1 libesd0 libexo-1-0 libexo-common libfaad2 libfile-listing-perl libfluidsynth1 libfm-data libfm-gtk-data libfm-gtk1 libfm1 libfont-afm-perl libgdome2-0 libgdome2-cpp-smart0c2a libglade2-0 libgoffice-0.8-8 libgoffice-0.8-8-common libgringotts2 libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgsm1 libgtkmathview0c2a libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libid3tag0 libimlib2 libio-socket-ssl-perl libjpeg-progs liblink-grammar4 libloudmouth1-0 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmailtools-perl libmcrypt4 libmcs1 libmenu-cache1 libmms0 libmowgli2 libmusicbrainz3-6 libnet-dbus-perl libnet-http-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libobrender27 libobt0 libonig2 liboobs-1-5 libopenal1 libopts25 libots0 libpisock9 libpolkit-gtk-1-0 libpostproc52 libresid-builder0c2a libschroedinger-1.0-0 libsidplay2 libsvga1 libswscale2 libtar0 libtie-ixhash-perl libtimedate-perl libts-0.0-0 libuniconf4.6 liburi-perl libva1 libvdpau1 libvpx0 libwebcam0 libwv-1.2-3 libwvstreams4.6-base libwvstreams4.6-extras libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfce4util4 libxfcegui4-4 libxfconf-0-2 libxml-parser-perl libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpath-perl libxss1 libxvidcore4 link-grammar-dictionaries-en lm-sensors lubuntu-artwork lubuntu-core lubuntu-default-settings lubuntu-desktop lubuntu-icon-theme lxappearance lxappearance-obconf lxde-common lxde-core lxdm lxinput lxkeymap lxlauncher lxmenu-data lxpanel lxpanel-indicator-applet-plugin lxrandr lxsession lxsession-edit lxshortcut lxtask lxterminal mplayer mtpaint ntp obconf openbox openbox-themes osmo pcmanfm pidgin pidgin-data pidgin-libnotify pidgin-microblog plymouth-theme-lubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-lubuntu-text scrot sylpheed sylpheed-doc sylpheed-i18n sylpheed-plugins synaptic system-tools-backends transmission tsconf ttf-lyx uvcdynctrl uvcdynctrl-data wvdial xfburn xfce-keyboard-shortcuts xfce4-power-manager xfce4-power-manager-data xfconf xfonts-100dpi xpad xscreensaver xscreensaver-data && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

For Ubuntu 13.04 Use this command

```
sudo apt-get remove abiword abiword-common abiword-plugin-grammar abiword-plugin-mathview ace-of-penguins audacious audacious-plugins chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n chromium-codecs-ffmpeg elementary-icon-theme esound-common galculator gdebi gdebi-core giblib1 gnome-icon-theme-full gnome-mplayer gnome-system-tools gnome-time-admin gnumeric gnumeric-common gnumeric-doc gpicview gtk2-engines-pixbuf guvcview hardinfo indicator-status-provider-pidgin leafpad libabiword-2.9 libaiksaurus-1.2-0c2a libaiksaurus-1.2-data libaiksaurusgtk-1.2-0c2a libaudclient2 libaudcore1 libaudiofile1 libavcodec53 libavformat53 libavutil51 libbinio1ldbl libcddb2 libcompfaceg1 libcue1 libdca0 libdirectfb-1.2-9 libdiscid0 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libenca0 libencode-locale-perl libept1.4.12 libesd0 libexo-1-0 libexo-common libfaad2 libfile-listing-perl libfluidsynth1 libfm-data libfm-gtk-data libfm-gtk3 libfm3 libfont-afm-perl libgdome2-0 libgdome2-cpp-smart0c2a libglade2-0 libgoffice-0.8-8 libgoffice-0.8-8-common libgringotts2 libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgsm1 libgtkmathview0c2a libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libid3tag0 libimlib2 libio-socket-ssl-perl libjpeg-progs liblink-grammar4 libloudmouth1-0 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmailtools-perl libmcrypt4 libmcs1 libmenu-cache2 libmms0 libmowgli2 libmusicbrainz3-6 libnet-dbus-perl libnet-http-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libobrender27 libobt0 libonig2 liboobs-1-5 libopenal1 libopts25 libots0 libpisock9 libpolkit-gtk-1-0 libpostproc52 libresid-builder0c2a libschroedinger-1.0-0 libsidplay2 libsvga1 libswscale2 libtar0 libtie-ixhash-perl libtimedate-perl libts-0.0-0 libuniconf4.6 liburi-perl libva1 libvdpau1 libvpx1 libwebcam0 libwv-1.2-4 libwvstreams4.6-base libwvstreams4.6-extras libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfce4util4 libxfcegui4-4 libxfconf-0-2 libxml-parser-perl libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpath-perl libxss1 libxvidcore4 link-grammar-dictionaries-en lm-sensors lubuntu-artwork lubuntu-core lubuntu-default-settings lubuntu-desktop lubuntu-icon-theme lxappearance lxappearance-obconf lxde-common lxde-core lxdm lxinput lxkeymap lxlauncher lxmenu-data lxpanel lxpanel-indicator-applet-plugin lxrandr lxsession lxsession-edit lxshortcut lxtask lxterminal mplayer mtpaint ntp obconf openbox openbox-themes osmo pcmanfm pidgin pidgin-data pidgin-libnotify pidgin-microblog plymouth-theme-lubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-lubuntu-text scrot sylpheed sylpheed-doc sylpheed-i18n sylpheed-plugins synaptic system-tools-backends transmission tsconf ttf-lyx uvcdynctrl uvcdynctrl-data wvdial xfburn xfce-keyboard-shortcuts xfce4-power-manager xfce4-power-manager-data xfconf xfonts-100dpi xpad xscreensaver xscreensaver-data && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: I followed the instructions on the linked page for 12.04 and it worked but it removed a couple things that I would have preferred to have kept. PHP5 and Chrome are what I've noticed so far. Nothing that can't be reinstalled, just a tiny bit more of a hassle than I initially realized.

Answer (score 5):

Evidently the lubuntu package over-writes some file.  I would re-install ubuntu-desktop and all its dependencies like [this](http://gourgi.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/re-install-ubuntu-desktop-metapackage-and-reinstall-its-dependencies/):

`sudo apt-cache depends ubuntu-desktop | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | sed '/^$/d' | grep -v 'i386' | xargs sudo apt-get install --reinstall --install-recommends --yes`

Comment: I got a huge error message part of this: **Note, selecting 'type-handling:i386' instead of 'i386:i386'**

Comment: That was addressed in one of the comments on the link...I added a grep in there for you

Comment: this one doesn't work.

Comment: I deleted it.  Someone in chat indicated that the other didn't work for them completely, so I put it back for them to try

Answer (score 2):

so to remove lubuntu-desktop you just have to:

`sudo apt-get remove lubuntu-desktop lubuntu-artwork plymouth-theme-lubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-lubuntu-text`

then `sudo apt-get auto-remove` for the rest.

Comment: this worked, it removed lubuntu.

Comment: Just as a note for others (informed Alvar over chat): I doubt this works for the reasons mentioned in a [similar question](http://askubuntu.com/q/122242/43660) on removing Kubuntu.

Alvar, if you check to see whether `openbox` (window manager), `pcmanfm` (file manager), etc are in `/usr/bin/`, you'll see they are still there.  Removing `lubuntu-desktop` doesn't remove all the stuff from the install.

Comment: ahh, so you really meant to ask how to change the Plymouth theme, or remove the themes for lubuntu, can you change your question to match you answer, as accepting this answer does not help future users in solving your original question.

Comment: @AnwarShah The command I posted removes the packages included in lubuntu-desktop and the meta-package. I don't see how your answer helps me?!

Comment: @AnwarShah I removed much more than just the lubuntu-desktop meta-package. did you read the whole line?

Comment: Yes, I read the whole line. I saw, you removed much more than the meta packages. As the second comment is saying, there are still many packages, which are not removed from your command. also `autoremove` option does not automatically remove dependencies of meta packages. I saw, you get bored and annoyed for my comment. FYI, I didn't give that downvote. Sorry, for creating annoyance. I'll remove my comments. Sorry again.

Answer (score 2):

[This link](http://complete-concrete-concise.com/ubuntu-2/ubuntu-11-10-how-to-completely-uninstall-remove-the-lubuntu-desktop) worked for me. Very easy to follow, just a bit of a lengthy process is all... 
I don't know if you need to, but just in case, after doing everything from the above link, I entered the following commands too:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Lubuntu completely removed ^_^

Comment: step 2 on that list is what you get when you auto-remove when you have removed lubuntu-desktop.