# How to restore plymouth default theme

Tags: grub2, plymouth, restore

I'm a newbie and I've got this issue:
My system has set up debian_5 theme but I want to get rid of it and restore the Ubuntu 11.10 default grub theme/splash/design (as you prefer) that is I think **plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo**. I installed/reinstalled it by Ubuntu Software Center, but it didn't anything.

[For your curiosity: The cause of that unwanted theme (debian 5) it's that I have tried lot of packages and now I can't restore the default grub design (that I liked so much!)]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the installed plymouth themes by typing the following command on Terminal:

`sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`

You’re supposed to select your desired plymouth theme by typing its number and then press [Enter]. After choosing and activating your desired plymouth theme, you have to “save” the changes by typing the following command:
`sudo update-initramfs -u`

Comment: My PC screen goes on energy saving during the booting so I can't say if I have actually set the desidered plymouth theme (Yep, I've just discovered another problem of my system!) However that command line should solve the problem I posted. For the other one issue I'll look for its different specific solution. Thanks Ashu!

Comment: I think mine could be a driver problem (?)

Comment: if you have any more problems you can post a new question... maybe i might b able to help you.

Comment: At the end I managed to remove that horrible bootsplash (of "debian theme 5") by removing the named "desktop-base" package from Synaptics

Comment: I also managed to see the boot animation of ubuntu! I don't know how. Possibility 1) after I run the following command lines I solved a graphic driver issue:
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
Possibility 2) I have updated from ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Plymouth Manager**. It is a program that can be used for theming Plymouth (so, you can choose the default theme).

This is the PPA you need:

https://launchpad.net/~mefrio-g/+archive/plymouthmanager

To add the PPA and install the program:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mefrio-g/plymouthmanager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install plymouth-manager
```

Then, if you don´t want to keep Plymouth Manager:

```
sudo apt-get purge plymouth-manager
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mefrio-g/plymouthmanager
```

Last line is needed for removing the PPA.

Ariel

Comment: If you're going to do stuff from the command line anyway, you might as well use `update-alternatives` as the [previous answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/122084/43660) suggests.  Then no need to install and remove some program.

Comment: Thank Ariel. This is also an alternative and pretty solution. For readers, this manager lets you choose, install and set theme in a really quick way.