# How to return the login screen to the default

Tags: unity, 12.04, kde, login-screen, desktop-environments

I've been experimenting with various Desktop Environments, including LXDE, XFCE, KDE.

I'm returning to Unity, and I would like my login screen back to the default for 12.04. I think that it changed when I tried KDE, probably because of an answer I gave to a prompt that I didn't understand.

Any ideas?

Comment: does this one answer your question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/2007/how-do-i-change-the-plymouth-bootscreen

Comment: If it does, it certainly could be more explicit. I'm confused after reading it. But I'm not at all sure if it is answering the same question.

Comment: Referring to the boot splash screen is a duplicate to [this one](http://askubuntu.com/q/122081/61218) and referring to revert back to lightdm login screen is a duplicate of [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/58023/how-can-i-make-lightdm-the-default-display-manager)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For getting back the default boot loading, use the following :

`sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`
, then choose whichever bootscreen you prefer, for default `/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth`, afterwards run this command `sudo update-initramfs -u`

For the login screen, run this command : `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Comment: You need as well to do the same for default.plymouth.grub
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth.grub

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for the last part of last answer:

Similar issue on 14.04 where "gdm" is again broken/no longer supported?

I was in a bind after reboot *I could no longer login to Ubuntu: **NO login screen** -- only a background and mouse (nothing else).
Then recalled I had selected "gdm" as default for lightdm reconfiguration once (as part of a successful package installation).

Login from a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>)
and then enter:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Then selecting default "lightdm" from the TTY menu choice.
I was able to restore a working login screen (and it still worked across reboot).

Basically after 12.04, never select anything but default "lightdm"...
(Unless you have installed something else that you know **for sure** will work -- e.g. KDE)