# Restoring Grub after Kubuntu installation

Tags: grub2, customization, restore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to restore plymouth default theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122081/how-to-restore-plymouth-default-theme)

I installed Kubuntu on top of my existing Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit) installation. During Kubuntu installation, I chose lightdm as my default display manager (instead of kdm).

Now  after rebooting, the Grub has a new color (gray instead of default purplish) and the screen while booting is gray (instead of purplish). I am curious if it is possible to change this grub behavior without removing Kubuntu.

I did find a lot of discussion about modifying grub themes but they were not very useful because I do not know what is the default unity grub theme.

I did reinstall grub but it didn't change anything.

I tried the [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) but couldn't succeed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Just follow [this instructions](http://ubuntuguide.net/change-login-screen-back-to-default-in-ubuntu-12-04):
Open terminal (ctrl+alt+t)

If you want to restore Ubuntu "booting" logo, run:

1.`sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`
 2. `sudo update-initramfs -u`

If you want to restore default login screen run:
 1.`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`
 2. click OK and choose Lightdm.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the splash (booting) screen by following the instructions in this question: 
[How to recover splash screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132120/how-to-recover-splash-screen)

I'm not sure how to restore the login screen. I'd love it if someone would post an answer to that. I've tried to find out myself with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Kubuntu over Ubuntu - not side-by-side, but as a replacement - your old Grub settings are lost.  Unless you told it otherwise during installation, Kubuntu wiped out the old Grub and installed its own - with its own defaults - and so now you have what you have.  You can again adjust it to be what you want, of course, following instructions given in other answers here.

If you installed Kubuntu next to Ubuntu, then it did the same thing, but your old Grub settings are still saved in your Ubuntu installation.  In this case, if you boot into Ubuntu and reinstall Grub from there, you will find that Grub will pick up your saved settings and be restored to how you had it before (except that now Kubuntu will also be listed as a boot option).

By the way, I find this annoying.  On one of my computers I usually have three versions of Linux installed: the current Ubuntu, the alpha or beta of the next version, and one other just for learning and/or experimenting (currently Tuquito).  I want Grub to keep the same settings through any new installations, except for updating the list; I wish new installations wouldn't always try to overwrite my previous Grub.  I've learned how to get around it deal with it, but it is an annoyance.

Comment: I think, that he only installs kbubntu-desktop - it changes plymouth, GRUB wallpaper and display manager.

Comment: Hmmm ... yeah, maybe that's what he did, although it's difficult to be sure from what he wrote.  I wouldn't think installing KDE on Ubuntu would do anything with Grub, but maybe so.  (I've never done that; when I wanted to try KDE, I just installed Kubuntu into a different partition.)

Answer (score -1):

For Grub2:

For Grub2 the images should follow these rules:

- Size should be 640×480
- Format should be .tga (The GIMP can do this)
- Follow the same design tips as above.
- Saved in /usr/share/images/grub/

open up the file `gksu gedit /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme` and look for the line:

WALLPAPER="/usr/share/images/desktop-base/moreblue-orbit-grub.png"

change the explicit path of the image in the line above to the path of your new image.

then

```
sudo update-grub2
```

[HERE IS THE SOURCE](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/10/17/change-your-grub-splash-screen-in-ubuntu/)