# How do I remove Lubuntu Desktop from Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: unity, 12.04, lubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to completely remove desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73993/how-to-completely-remove-desktop)

When I installed Ubuntu 12.04 Beta 2 on my computer I also added the lubuntu desktop to try using the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lubuntu-desktop/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

How do I remove lubuntu and restore my Unity configuration?

[How do I remove lubuntu-desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118712/how-do-i-remove-lubuntu-desktop)
This link applies to 11.10 only

Comment: You do know that `lubuntu-desktop` is an official flavor of Ubuntu and thus it is on the 12.04 repositories right? Why are you adding a PPA to install something that you can already install? You need to remove the PPA with `ppa-purge` and remove the packages just like on the other question, these are the same.

Comment: No I didnt know, but Im learning fast thanks to this site. Although I have been using Ubuntu for a few years I am relatively new in terms of understanding some of the concepts of PPAs and repositories etc.  I got the PPA on an article from a different site, read it and decided to use it. (Lesson learned). Thanks again Bruno

Comment: @BrunoPereira You shouldn't be linking to that other question.  That whole thread is a mess.  The OP there won't even let me tag the question correctly with the plymouth tag.  Re-open this thread, and we can put things right, including an updated answer like the psychocats link, but updated for 12.04.

Comment: Voting to open, this is stuck in a duplicate/close cycle with the other answers.

Comment: Marco Ceppi has changed the link to a better duplicate, negating my earlier comment.