# How to remove unity and the default desktop  environment of Ubuntu

Tags: unity, gnome, uninstall, lubuntu, desktop-environments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you remove Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6302/how-can-you-remove-unity)
>   [How to completely remove desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73993/how-to-completely-remove-desktop)

I have installed LXDE from Ubuntu software center,(didn't install the addons i.e. chromium, GUI login manager, lxtask).

Now while logging in I have options allowing me to choose between LXDE and unity 3d and 2d ,gnome.  So how do I remove all those other desktop environments and keep LXDE just like in lubuntu, but i want to keep my installed programs.  I'm using 12.04LTS.

Comment: Do you want to remove completely, or just the options in the login screen?

Comment: To remove only Unity,  Follow [jokerdino's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/126993/63025)