# Remove kubuntu-desktop from ubuntu 12.04

Tags: kubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to completely remove desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73993/how-to-completely-remove-desktop)

So, I thought I managed to remove KDE completely, but apparently that did not work at all, because every KDE application is back, including the KDE splash screen.

I ran

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge kubuntu-desktop
```

Then I ran

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Then I ran

```
sudo sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

Then I rebooted and everything seemed to be the original ubuntu-desktop (without the kde splash screen and other KDE applications). But now, one week later I still boot to ubuntu-desktop, but like I said, the kde splash screen and applications are all back.

How should I remove kubuntu-desktop?

Comment: @Meijuh just follow the link provided by penreturn and get your cemented desktop remove.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have to delete each dependency by hand:

```
apt-cache depends kubuntu-desktop
```

These scripts should work for 12.04: [www.psychocats.net](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/purexubuntu)

Comment: Well I did just that and now i am getting the following error.

   Unpacking libqtcore4 (from .../libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 conffile './etc/xdg/Trolltech.conf' is not in sync with other instances of the same package
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb

Comment: After issueing apt-get install -f, I got broken packages, because libqtcore4 would not install. Magically, I was able to remove libqtcore4 via synaptic and then reinstall it via apt-get.

Comment: So - does it work now? And do you think it is an issue caused by one of the scripts mentioned in the link above?