# How to remove kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 (using wubi)dual booting with Windows 7. Having read that Kubuntu desktop has similarities to Windows I later downloaded Kubuntu. I have since concluded that Kubuntu offers no advantage over Ubuntu and would therefore like to remove Kubuntu. Could somebody please tell me how to do this, leaving just Ubuntu. May I have any answers as idiot proof as possible please.

Answer (score 1):

The following commands will install the Unity Desktop as is packaged with Ubuntu and remove the KDE Desktop as is packaged with Kubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get purge kubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

[THIS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191693/remove-kubuntu-desktop-from-ubuntu-12-04) link and [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73993/how-to-completely-remove-desktop) link may be useful to you

Answer (score 0):

Aside from removing the kde applications, and replacing them with unity (maybe another answer could give you more insight on that topic) i would simply reinstall ubuntu...

- DL ubuntu from the official website
- create a bootable medium as described on the official ubuntu website
- boot said medium from your bios
- proceed with installation

I know its an over simplified solution... But it would undeniably fix your issue