# Unable to remove KDE Plasma Workspace login

Tags: 12.04, kde, plasma

I installed ubuntu 12.0.4 recently and then on top of it tried installing KDE plasma workspace.
I now want to get rid of KDE plasma workspace and have ran all commands available on forum and most stuff is gone but the login screen still has the option to login to KDE plasma workspace.

How can i get rid of login option to KDE plasma workspace?

Comment: Have you removed the kde-workspace-data ? The kde-workspace-data is installing the /usr/share/xsessions/kde-plasma.desktop and this file is offering the KDE plasma workspace login option.

Comment: How to remove kde-workspace-data, can you tell me the steps?

Comment: 'sudo apt-get purge kde-workspace-data' or 'sudo apt-get remove kde-workspace-data' or start your favorite package manager and search the kde-workspace-data and remove it. Earlier: http://askubuntu.com/questions/73993/how-to-completely-remove-desktop