# Remains left after converting Lubuntu to Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, desktop-environments, lxde

I've installed a Lubuntu Raring (which was the only ISO I had that would boot on the PC I tried to install Kubuntu) and installed `kubuntu-desktop` and then did `do-release-upgrade`.

Now I've got a Kubuntu Saucy (Upgrade without problems), but there are still remains from LXDE/lubuntu-desktop left. As an example, I can still select Openbox and LXDE as desktop environments on login.

I've found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/74021/194948) to a similar question, but it's about converting to Xubuntu Quantal and I'd like to know whether there are differences in removing Lubuntu Saucy packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there aren't no differences. You can just

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove abiword abiword-common abiword-plugin-grammar abiword-plugin-mathview  ace-of-penguins audacious audacious-plugins audacious-plugins-data blueman  chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n chromium-codecs-ffmpeg  elementary-icon-theme esound-common galculator gdebi gdebi-core  gecko-mediaplayer giblib1 gnome-icon-theme-full gnome-mplayer gnome-system-tools  gnome-time-admin gnumeric gnumeric-common gnumeric-doc gpicview  gtk2-engines-pixbuf guvcview hardinfo indicator-status-provider-pidgin leafpad  libaacs0 libabiword-2.9 libaudclient2 libaudcore1 libaudiofile1 libbinio1ldbl  libbluray1 libbs2b0 libcddb2 libcompfaceg1 libcue1 libencode-locale-perl  libept1.4.12 libesd0 libexo-1-0 libexo-common libexo-helpers  libfile-listing-perl libfluidsynth1 libfm-data libfm-gtk-data libfm-gtk1 libfm1  libfont-afm-perl libgdome2-0 libgdome2-cpp-smart0c2a libglade2-0 libgmlib0  libgmtk0 libgmtk0-data libgoffice-0.8-8 libgoffice-0.8-8-common libgringotts2  libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgtkmathview0c2a libguess1 libhtml-form-perl  libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl  libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl  libhttp-negotiate-perl libid3tag0 libimlib2 libio-socket-inet6-perl  libio-socket-ssl-perl libjpeg-progs libjpeg-turbo-progs liblink-grammar4  libloudmouth1-0 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl  libmailtools-perl libmcrypt4 libmenu-cache1 libmowgli2 libmpg123-0  libnet-dbus-perl libnet-http-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libobrender27 libobt0  libonig2 liboobs-1-5 libopts25 libots0 libpisock9 libresid-builder0c2a  libsidplay2 libsocket6-perl libtar0 libtidy-0.99-0 libtie-ixhash-perl  libtimedate-perl libuniconf4.6 liburi-perl libvdpau1 libwebcam0 libwv-1.2-4  libwvstreams4.6-base libwvstreams4.6-extras libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl  libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfce4util4 libxfconf-0-2  libxml-parser-perl libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpath-perl libxss1  lightdm-gtk-greeter link-grammar-dictionaries-en lm-sensors lubuntu-artwork  lubuntu-artwork-12-04 lubuntu-core lubuntu-default-settings lubuntu-desktop  lubuntu-icon-theme lubuntu-software-center lxappearance lxappearance-obconf  lxinput lxkeymap lxlauncher lxmenu-data lxpanel lxpanel-indicator-applet-plugin  lxrandr lxsession lxsession-edit lxshortcut lxtask lxterminal mplayer2 mtpaint  ntp obconf openbox openbox-themes osmo pcmanfm pidgin pidgin-data  pidgin-libnotify pidgin-microblog plymouth-theme-lubuntu-logo  plymouth-theme-lubuntu-text python-pysqlite2 python-xklavier scrot sylpheed  sylpheed-doc sylpheed-i18n sylpheed-plugins synaptic system-tools-backends  transmission ttf-lyx uvcdynctrl uvcdynctrl-data wvdial xfburn  xfce-keyboard-shortcuts xfce4-power-manager xfce4-power-manager-data xfconf  xfonts-100dpi xpad xscreensaver xscreensaver-data
```

to remove everything from your recent Lubuntu installation.

Comment: Do i have to re-install `kubuntu-desktop` afterwards?

Comment: You don't have to. You already have kubuntu-desktop when you upgraded to Kubuntu Saucy.

Comment: `man apt-get` doesn't show the option `--auto-remove`... What do I have to use?

Comment: It does. You just have to scroll down a little bit more. :-)

Comment: May it be you gave me the Xubuntu removal command? There's much xfce4 stuff listed and, by the way, it's not working.

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: `Package "indicator-status-provide-pidgin " isn't installed, won't be removed`, same for "libxfce4util" and then six `E: Package lib... couldn't be` found` (...= libfm-gtk1, libfm1, libgmlib0, libgmtk0, libgmtk0-data, libmenu-cache) After this it falls back to command prompt. This is everything that appears after "reading status information" (Everything translated from german)

Comment: I see. You can remove those packages from the command and then proceed again.

Comment: If you are not familiar with the packages included in the Lubuntu desktop, you may want to see the list here http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/lubuntu-desktop

Comment: Now it's working. But it says it's removing every single KDE application... so I guess I really have to reinstall kubuntu-desktop

Comment: Alright. Enjoy the eye-candy with KDE! :-)

Comment: It deleted any desktop environment-related packages... I'm unable to start lightdm... I cannot establish an internet connection... What went wrong? Edit: Got internet