# How to re-organize my desktop environments?

Tags: unity, xubuntu, kubuntu, desktop-environments

I wanted to try out some different desktop environment other than Unity so I installed `kubuntu-desktop` using

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

then I didn't like it so much, so I removed it according to an answer to one of the questions here by executing

```
sudo apt-get purge kubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

but apparently this did not completely remove it as I still noticed that I could still choose KDE Plasma from my login screen, some programs that were installed with this desktop environment are still installed, I still have my start up and shutdown screens in black and say kubuntu, etc.

I tried to re-install `ubuntu-desktop` using

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

in a try to get my start up/shutdown screens back to be consistent with the currently installed desktop environment at the time (i.e., `ubuntu-desktop`), but this wasn't successful.

I then installed `xubuntu-desktop` using

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

and now I'm still having my start up/shutdown kubuntu black screens in addition to xubuntu login screen and I didn't see an option in the xubuntu login screen to get back to Unity if I wanted to though.

My questions now is,  in this situation, how to completely remove `kubuntu-desktop` and everything that is related and keep `ubuntu-desktop` and `xubuntu-desktop` installed?

Thank you!

Comment: Try this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/73993/how-to-completely-remove-desktop?rq=1 and http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntucat/tag/pure-ubuntu/

Comment: @Muzaffar unfortunately, this didn't work either.

Comment: The problem appears to be solved by @Vidit's answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/549041/207935)!