# How to list the packages to be installed by installing a specific package?

Tags: 14.04, package-management

Pardon this newbie question, but I've [previously](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577602/how-to-re-organize-my-desktop-environments) run into serious issues as I wanted to try other desktop environments other than the default one in Ubuntu, precisely because I didn't know how to completely remove some/all of them and get back to the default settings.

I think I ran into these issues because I didn't know which packages to remove as I didn't know which packages were installed at the first place. Commands like

```
sudo apt-get purge <package name>
```

still left some applications installed on my system that were originally installed by the original package.

I have a couple of questions here

1. how do I list all the packages to be installed by installing a specific package and see which of these packages are already installed on my machine (if any)?
2. I imagine purging only the new packages that were installed by this specific package would get things back to the default settings. Is that right? Is there an easy, quick, and effective way to get things back to the default settings (aside from backing up my data)?

Comment: You can see which packets would get installed by apt-get before actually installing them when you have it do a dry-run: `sudo apt-get install -s MyNewProgramm` where the `-s` means _simulate_. However, this only shows what packages would get installed on your current system, not which packages are included into your installed one generally (those you already have installed won't show up).

Comment: @ByteCommander no need to use `sudo` with `-s`. Will save you from really dangerous typos... ;-)

Comment: @Rmano Oh, you're right. But without sudo you get an ugly hint that it will need root privileges for the real execution. However, without sudo could be better here anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic command to show dependencies is

```
apt-cache depends <package>
```

which will show you the dependencies (there is even a `rdepends` option to show the reversed dependencies).

You can add this to the @ByteCommander's suggestion to use simulate install to see which packages will be installed in your system:

```
apt-get install -s ubuntu-desktop
```

(no need to use `sudo` in simulated mode!)

But to really answer the question, no, it is not possible sometime to go *completely* back. A classical example is `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` (Gnome shell) and `ubuntu-desktop` (Unity). Their dependencies partly overlap --- for example:

```
[romano:~] % apt-cache depends ubuntu-desktop | grep seah
  Depends: seahorse
[romano:~] % apt-cache depends ubuntu-gnome-desktop | grep seah
  Depends: seahorse
```

...and the overlapping packages *may have different configuration defaults*.

You can approximate the thing you want by purging all the packages and reinstalling them --- but it can be really dangerous, because the intermediate step can be a non-functional  system.

Even outside of the packages, sometime the DEs make changes in your home directory that *can* affect other DEs (and files in your home are not restored even using `purge` and `reinstall`). So if you want to check another DE, do that with a fresh new user.

My personal experience is that the "insulation" of the various desktop environments is not perfect at all; Unity and Gnome shell are the worst offenders (probably because they share a lot), with other it can be better --- I do not know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But isn't there even a way to take like a snapshot of these configuration defaults and apply them back as necessary?

Comment: There is still no automated snapshot-rollback functionality in Ubuntu (although you should be able to hack it with `brtfs` filesystem...); I normally use a virtual machine for that kind of things. Most of this applies: http://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version

Comment: One more thing please regarding your edit, is it guaranteed that if I install any package in general, or a desktop environment in particular, with a new user that everything will be installed locally?

Comment: @Kareem no. The two problems are independent --- you will have *both* of them. Using a new user will only solve the home directory problem. The other stands. A virtual machine or a container (this one I know too little to help) is the only solution I think. Maybe you can research starting here: http://xmodulo.com/lxc-containers-ubuntu.html

Comment: Yeah, I know about VMs and actually use them, but I was just looking for a way that saves the time of trying things out. Thank you anyway!